# Setup my Development Environment c and c++ using qtcreator and clang

Tags: build, compilation, clang, qt-creator, clang++

I am new member of Stackoverflow. 
i have a question to ask and I hope for complete answer.

Please can you give me tutorial or the steps to setup my development environment?

1. I want to install the clang to compile both 32bit and 64bit application and how to switch between them
2. if I have succeeded in installing clang what file do I choose to put in my IDE?? I have qtCreator and I have to put 2 file the  compilation and the debugger
3. I have make same research on the most popular library and I found that most of them do not support clang so I have to build the source of the library by myself so can you give me an example how to do it? Let’s choose qt 5.2 how can I build it?

Thanks a lot guys you will save me trouble if you help me. I am searching this for a long time

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I am asking for help like many topics in this forum I don’t know anything that’s why I cannot describe the problem. I just install qtcreator and download the source code of qt 5.4